# What ways are there to use parallelisation in quantum machine learning?

Tags: quantum-enhanced-machine-learning, quantum-parallelism

In classical machine learning, GPUs have been used successfully to parallelise the training as well as the inference process.  Does quantum machine learning have the same potential to operate with parallel QPUs?